# Access external HD formatted as Mac OSX Extended (Journaled) from Windows PC

Tags: media-server, file-server

Hi Knowledgeable Interneters! This question has probably been answered somewhere before but i'm an RPi noob and apparently can't figure out the right search terms to find what i'm looking for. I've seen several relevant tutorials but I couldn't tell if they would actually get me everything I wanted.

I have an external HD full of movies/music. The disk was formatted on a Mac and can only be accessed by a Mac. The Mac has long since died and been replaced by several Windows PCs which can't access that HD (I think it's formatted Mac OSX Extended Journaled but i'm not entirely sure). I want to be able to access that HD over the local network from any of several Windows PCs I now have in my home. Streaming would be nice but is not required and I do have a lot of other data on there that's not movies or music.

Any recommendations or advice? Which RPi OS distro should I use? What services should I install -- samba, xbmc, something else entirely? Got links for any tutorials that can make this happen?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=60437) you can add support for [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) (Apple's proprietary file system for MacOS) by executing the following command on Raspbian:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs
```

Without any additional work this may result in the file system being mounted read-only which may not be a problem is you are just interested in reading the existing files.  From what I've read the Linux software for HFS+ doesn't support writing to a journaled HFS+ file system and journaling needs to be disabled using MacOS.

Once you have the file system mounted read-only you should be able to use Samba to share out the drive to your Windows PCs.

[Here's a article](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/) that describes how to do that.  You will need to perform the Samba installation and configuration steps described in this article beginning with:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```

You should substitute your path to your mounted HFS+ drive for `/media/USBHDD1/` which is used in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As long you only need read access, you can use the **hfs Explorer** to extract the files. You can find the Tool [here](http://www.heise.de/download/hfsexplorer.html) (I am sure you will find a site in your language, this link was the first that Google throw at me ;)

There is also a [Video Titorial](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LUApUZFA6Wk) how to use the tool.

I used it myself, it is a little bit slow, but it works.

Comment: There is as far I know also a way to load hpfs Support onto a Linux box. Sharing it then through cifs to Windows clients might be possible, but to be honest in my opinion the performance will be weak.

Comment: Maybe if it is really hpfs you should extract the files. Place them somewhere else, format the HDD into another format and than copy the files back. Sorry, I know that is not exactly the answer you were looking for. :( maybe somebody else have a better advise.